# Blackberry Java Development - Increment version number

Tags: java, blackberry, version, numbers

I am using Eclipse to develop a Blackberry Java application.Is possible to automatically increment version number on every build like its done in Visual Studio ?

Comment: I have the same pb. How did you resolve your problem? Where did you put the file build.xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Ant under Eclipse, you can use the `<buildnumber>` task. See [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0532.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you can try using subversion http://subversion.apache.org/
for project standard development. try using maven http://maven.apache.org/